# What could be the reason for getting the error "multiple definitions" while linking?

Tags: c, gcc

I keep getting errors that my functions have been defined multiple times. Of course I only have one file and one function with that name in my file. Where could gcc find those other definitions?

Here is an example error message, but I get many of those:

> /tmp/ccerCzAD.o:main.c:(.text+0xdb):
>
> first defined here
>
> /tmp/ccGbaGfJ.o: In function `at':
>
> dlist.c:(.text+0xe3): multiple definition of `at'

I included "stdio.h" and "stdlib.h". Is the function "at()" maybe already defined in one of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're defining the function in the header file, as opposed to declaring it.

```
int at(void); /* declaration */
```

```
int at(void) { return 0; } /* definition */
```

The usual way is to put declarations in header files and definitions in code files.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the accepted answer, because it is basically what I did. Although I am not sure why in that case I get multiple definitions.

Comment: After reading your comment to Tom's answer, I figure you're compiling `dlist.c` twice: once through a command line parameter and again through inclusion in `main.c`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Function at seems to be defined in files dlist.c and main.c

Could this be the case?

file dlist.h

```
int at();
```

file dlist.c

```
int at(){return 0;}
```

file main.c

```
#include "dlist.h"

int at(){return 1;}
int main()
{
       return at();
}
```

Comment: Or maybe he put `int at(){return 0;}` in the header file? ??

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was not my problem actually, but it made me realize my mistake. I accidentally put "dlist.c" instead of "dlist.h" in "main.c".

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to:

```
#ifndef _DLIST_H
#define _DLIST_H

int at();

#endif
```

To prevent the same error when using `#include` to include the same header in multiple `.c` files.